# Setting up vscode for c++ in linux

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, cmake

I am trying to set up vscode to do c++ programming on linux. I am confused about the instructions given. Do I need either one or both of these things given below to compile and debug my c++ code?

Can I use only cmake to compile run and debug my code? If so, do I still need the tasks.json and launch.json?

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux

Answer (score 1):

You can use cmake extension [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools).

Follow the setup instructions from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux)

I use it and it works perfectly.

Comment: so you just use this for both debugging and running your code?

Comment: @user3702643 yeah

Comment: whats the difference between using the gcc compiler instructions and using cmake instructions?

Comment: @user3702643 `gcc` is the compiler tool and `cmake` is the build tool